# What is the easiest way to create readable JSON string?

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift4

I want to draw formatted JSON string with new lines and tabs (or spaces).

But the code below yields string as long one lined text.

`let resultString = String(data: response.data, encoding: .utf8)`

Is there any default method to create multiline JSON string?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonserialization.writingoptions/1418364-prettyprinted

Comment: And this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/jsonencoder.outputformatting/2919679-prettyprinted for the Swift 4 JSONEncoder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prettyPrinted` option of `JSONSerialization`

```
do {
    let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: response.data, options: []) as! [String: AnyObject]
    let formattedJson = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: json, options:JSONSerialization.WritingOptions.prettyPrinted )
    if let formattedString = String(data: formattedJson, encoding: .utf8) {
        print(formattedString)
    }
} catch {
    print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

As for the `JSONEncoder` introduced in Swift 4, there is a `prettyPrinted` option:

```
struct Foo: Codable {
    var bar: String
    var baz: Int
}

let foo = Foo(bar: "gfdfs", baz: 334)

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted // This makes it formatted as multiline

let data = try encoder.encode(foo)
print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
```

The output is:

```
{
  "bar" : "gfdfs",
  "baz" : 334
}
```